# Анимация не производится JQurey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Решил сделать самую простою анимацию появления текста методом `$("span").show("slow");`

Но когда обновляю сайт,анимация не происходит почему не пойму,вот код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("span").show("slow");

    });

    </script>

    <body>

        <div class="b1">        
        </div>
        <div class="text_block_1" >
                <span>Hello</span>
        </div>


    </body> 

    <style>
    body
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .b1
    {
        height:1025px;
        width:1931px;
        margin-top:-3%;
        margin-left:-1%;
        border:0px red solid;
        background-image:url('https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/2560x1440/d/4c/hi-tech-technology-noutbuk.jpg');
        background-size:100%;

    }

    @font-face{
        font-family:low;
        src:url('12222.ttf');
    }
    .text_block_1{
        width:1800px;
        height:700px;
        margin-top:-41%;
        margin-left:24%;
        border:0px black solid;
    }

    span 
    {
        font-family:low;
        font-size: 48px;
        line-height: 2em;
        background: #696969;
        color:white;
        padding:10px;

    }


    </style>

</html>
```

Comment: @igor Спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Какая анимация появления может быть у элемента, который и так виден?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").show("slow");
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="b1">
  </div>
  <div class="text_block_1">
    <span>Hello</span>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  .b1 {
    height: 1025px;
    width: 1931px;
    margin-top: -3%;
    margin-left: -1%;
    border: 0px red solid;
    background-image: url('https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/2560x1440/d/4c/hi-tech-technology-noutbuk.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: low;
    src: url('12222.ttf');
  }
  
  .text_block_1 {
    width: 1800px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: -41%;
    margin-left: 24%;
    border: 0px black solid;
  }
  
  span {
    font-family: low;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 2em;
    background: #696969;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .text_block_1 span {
    display:none;
  }
</style>

</html>
```